# c++ assistance needed for this project

Tags: c++

ok so i have just recently started doing programming in c++ with no experience of other languages.

i started out great with a simple minded idea for the school project but somehow it lost me in the code i was trying to create.

the idea is as follows, i want to create a program that first gives me a menu of "start" "load" "highscore" then as you choose one of them you get what it says :P so i started off with some basic struct to include the points i assign after each question to a .txt document then some if and switch-case and a do-while so if you fail you get choice to restart.

the code i have done so far( very far away from being complete but this is as far as i have gotten)(svar means answer / fraga mean question):

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <cstdlib>
    using namespace std;

   struct highscore{
   int svar;
   }

   int main(){

bool fail = true;
int svar = 0, fraga;
char val;
do{
    cout << " Menu" \n;
    cout << " 1. Start" \n;
    cout << " 2. Load" \n;
    cout << " 3. Credits" \n;
    cin >> val;
    switch(val){

          case '1':
    ofstream utFil;
    utFil.open("highscore.txt", ios::app);
    if (!utFil){
    cout << "file could not open";
    exit (1);
    }

                     cout << "WELCOME TO THE CISCO QUIZ\n"  "GOOD LUCK\n \n \n" ;
                     cout << "how many layers are there in the OSI model?" \n "4"\n   "5"\n "or 7?" \n;
                     cin >> fraga;
                     switch(fraga){
                                  case '4':

                                       cout << "Game Over!"\n;
                                       cout << "Do you wish to restart? (answer with 1 for yes and 2 for no)\n";
                                       cin >> fail;
                                       if(fail != '1'){
                                               fail = false;
                                               }
                                       break;

                                  case '5':

                                       cout << "Game Over!"\n;
                                       cout << "Do you wish to restart? (answer with 1 for yes, 2 for no)\n";
                                       cin >> fail;
                                       if(fail != '1'){
                                               fail = false;
                                               }
                                       break;

                                  case '7':
                                       svar = svar + 5;
                                       break;
                                       }

                                       if(svar == 5){
                                          cout << "what is name full name of OSPF?" \n;
                                          cout << "1. Open Shortest Path First" \n;
                                          cout << "2. Online Shooting Pro Fishing" \n;
                                          cout << "3. On Short Path First"\n ;
                                          cin >> fraga;
                                          switch(fraga){

                                                          case '1':
                                                          svar = svar + 5; 
                                                          }                                                                                  

                                                          case '2':
                                                               cout << "Game Over!"\n;
                                                               cout << "Do you wish to restart? (answer with yes, YES or Yes)"\n;
                                                               cin >> fail;
                                                               if(fail != '1'){
                                                               fail = false;
                                                                }
                                                               break;
                                                               }

                                                          case '3':
                                                               cout << "Game Over!"\n;
                                                               cout << "Do you wish to restart? (answer with yes, YES or Yes)"\n;
                                                               cin >> fail;
                                                                 if(fail != '1'){
                                                                     fail = false;
                                                                 }
                                                                 }
                                                                 }
                     if(svar == 10){
                     cout << "What does TTL mean?" \n;
                     cout << "1. Twin Twitched Life"\n;
                     cout << "2. Two Time Lives"\n;
                     cout << "3. Time To Live"\n;
                     cin >> fraga;                                  
                       switch(fraga){
                         case '1':
                          cout << "Game Over!"\n;
                          cout << "Do you wish to restart? (answer with yes, YES or Yes)"\n;
                          cin >> fail;
                           if(fail != '1'){
                           fail = false;
                           }
                         break;
                         }

                       case '2':
                         cout << "Game Over!"\n;
                         cout << "Do you wish to restart? (answer with 1 for yes and 2 for no)"\n;
                         cin >> fail;
                          if(fail != '1'){
                          fail = false;
                          }
                       break;
                       }

                       case '3':
                       svar = svar + 10;
                       break;
                       }
                     }

                      if(svar == 20){
                              cout << "What is the first command you enter on a Cisco router?"\n;
                              cout << " 1. enable"\n;
                              cout << " 2. disable"\n;
                              cout << " 3. enter"\n;
                              cin >> fraga;

                              switch(fraga){
                                            case '1':
                                                 svar = svar + 5;
                                                 break;

                                            case '2':
                                                 cout << "Game Over!"\n;
                                                 cout << "Do you wish to restart? (answer with 1 for yes and 2 for no)"\n;
                                                 cin >> fail;
                                                  if(fail != '1'){
                                                  fail = false;
                                                  }
                                                 break;
                                            case '3':
                                                 cout << "Game Over!"\n;
                                                 cout << "Do you wish to restart? (answer with 1 for yes and 2 for no)"\n;
                                                 cin >> fail;
                                                  if(fail != '1'){
                                                  fail = false;
                                                  }
                                                 break;
                                                 }                                         
                                                 }

                                  if(svar == 25){
                                          cout << "which protocol is the most prefered?"
                                          cout << " 1. RIP"\n;
                                          cout << " 2. EGRP"\n;
                                          cout << " 3. EIGRP"\n;
                                          cin >> fraga;
                                          switch(fraga){
                                                        case '1':
                                                               cout << "Game Over!"\n;
                                                               cout << "Do you wish to restart? (answer with 1 for yes and 2 for no)"\n;
                                                               cin >> fail;
                                                               if(fail != '1'){
                                                               fail = false;
                                                               }
                                                               break;
                                                               }    

                                                         case '2':
                                                              cout << "Game Over!"\n;
                                                              cout << "Do you wish to restart? (answer with 1 for yes and 2 for no)"\n;
                                                              cin >> fail;
                                                               if(fail != '1'){
                                                                fail = false;
                                                                 }
                                                                break;
                                                                }  

                                                        case '3':
                                                             svar = svar + 15;
                                                             break;
                                                             }     
                                                             }

                            utFil.close();



    }        
    }
```

and as you can see this confuses me and probably you as well got any tips i will be very grateful

thx for help :>

ok so since i have just joined this forum i am not allowed to answer my own question just yet so i have decided to update my original and send the code again but this time with another problem.This time i can not get the score to save into a .txt file it only creates a .txt but keeps it empty this is how the updated code looks like:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <cstdlib>
    using namespace std;
    struct highscore{

    int svar;
    };


    int main(){
ofstream highscore;            
bool fail = true;
int svar = 0, fraga, lost;
char val;
do{
    cout << " Menu" << endl;
    cout << " 1. Start" << endl;
    cout << " 2. Load" << endl;
    cout << " 3. Credits" << endl;
    cin >> val;
    switch(val){

          case '1':

                  highscore.open("Highscore.txt", ios::app);
                  if (!highscore){
                  cout << "file could not open";
                  exit (1);

                  }


                     cout << "WELCOME TO THE CISCO QUIZ  GOOD LUCK" << endl;
                     cout << "how many layers are there in the OSI model?" << endl;
                     cout << "1. 4" << endl;
                     cout << "2. 5" << endl;
                     cout << "3. 7" << endl;
                     cin >> fraga;
                     switch(fraga){
                                  case 1:

                                       cout << "Game Over!" << endl;
                                       cout << "Do you wish to restart? (answer with 1 for yes and 2 for no)" << endl;
                                       cin >> lost;
                                       if(lost == 2 ){
                                               fail = false;
                                               }
                                       break;

                                  case 2:

                                       cout << "Game Over!" << endl;
                                       cout << "Do you wish to restart? (answer with 1 for yes, 2 for no)" << endl;
                                       cin >> lost;
                                       if(lost == 2 ){
                                               fail = false;
                                               }
                                       break;

                                  case 3:
                                       svar = svar + 5;
                                       break;
                                  default:
                                    cout << "error" << endl;
                                       }

                                       if(svar == 5){
                                          cout << "what is the full name of OSPF?" << endl;
                                          cout << "1. Open Shortest Path First" << endl;
                                          cout << "2. Online Shooting Pro Fishing" << endl;
                                          cout << "3. On Short Path First" << endl;
                                          cin >> fraga;
                                          switch(fraga){

                                                          case 1:
                                                          svar = svar + 5; 
                                                               break;                                                                             

                                                          case 2:
                                                               cout << "Game Over!"<< endl;
                                                               cout << "Do you wish to restart? (answer with 1 for yes, 2 for no)" << endl;
                                                               cin >> lost;
                                                               if(lost == 2 ){
                                                                  fail = false;
                                                                  }
                                                               break;


                                                          case 3:
                                                               cout << "Game Over!" << endl;
                                                               cout << "Do you wish to restart? (answer with 1 for yes, 2 for no)" << endl;
                                                               cin >> lost;
                                                               if(lost == 2 ){
                                                                  fail = false;
                                                                 }
                                                                 }
                                                                 }

                     if(svar == 10){
                     cout << "What does TTL mean?" << endl;
                     cout << "1. Twin Twitched Life" << endl;
                     cout << "2. Two Time Lives" << endl;
                     cout << "3. Time To Live" << endl;
                     cin >> fraga;                                  
                       switch(fraga){
                         case 1:
                          cout << "Game Over!" << endl;
                          cout << "Do you wish to restart? (answer with yes, YES or Yes)"<< endl;
                          cin >> lost;
                                  if(lost == 2 ){
                                     fail = false;
                                       }
                         break;


                       case 2:
                         cout << "Game Over!" << endl;
                         cout << "Do you wish to restart? (answer with 1 for yes and 2 for no)" << endl;
                         cin >> lost;
                            if(lost == 2 ){
                                 fail = false;
                                     }
                       break;


                       case 3:
                       svar = svar + 10;
                       break;
                       }
                       }

                      if(svar == 20){
                              cout << "What is the first command you enter on a Cisco router?" << endl;
                              cout << " 1. enable"<< endl;
                              cout << " 2. disable" << endl;
                              cout << " 3. enter" << endl;
                              cin >> fraga;

                              switch(fraga){
                                            case 1:
                                                 svar = svar + 5;
                                                 break;

                                            case 2:
                                                 cout << "Game Over!" << endl;
                                                 cout << "Do you wish to restart? (answer with 1 for yes and 2 for no)" << endl;
                                                 cin >> lost;
                                                  if(lost == 2 ){
                                                       fail = false;
                                                               }
                                                 break;
                                            case 3:
                                                 cout << "Game Over!" << endl;
                                                 cout << "Do you wish to restart? (answer with 1 for yes and 2 for no)" << endl;
                                                 cin >> lost;
                                                  if(lost == 2 ){
                                                     fail = false;
                                                                }
                                                 break;
                                                 }                                         
                                                 }

                                  if(svar == 25){
                                          cout << "which protocol is the most prefered?" << endl;
                                          cout << " 1. RIP" << endl;
                                          cout << " 2. EGRP" << endl;
                                          cout << " 3. EIGRP" << endl;
                                          cin >> fraga;
                                          switch(fraga){
                                                        case 1:
                                                               cout << "Game Over!" << endl;
                                                               cout << "Do you wish to restart? (answer with 1 for yes and 2 for no)" << endl;
                                                               cin >> lost;
                                                                   if(lost == 2 ){
                                                                       fail = false;
                                                                                 }
                                                               break;


                                                         case 2:
                                                              cout << "Game Over!"<< endl;
                                                              cout << "Do you wish to restart? (answer with 1 for yes and 2 for no)" << endl;
                                                              cin >> lost;
                                                               if(lost == 2 ){
                                                                    fail = false;
                                                                             }
                                                                break;


                                                        case 3:
                                                             svar = svar + 15;
                                                             break;
                                                        }
                                                 }                                                           

              highscore.close();                                                 

     case '2':
        cout << "Still working on it" << endl;
        break;

    case '3':
        cout << "made by trickjay the most awesome guy on the planet!!!" << endl;
        break;
    default:
     cout << "Error try again" << endl;



    }       
    }while(fail);
    }
```

how do i get my code to save the scores into a .txt file and not just create a .txt?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read the [faq]. You'll get a badge (c:

Comment: Maybe try asking at [codereview.se], although, I would really clean up the question first. There is no excuse for poor spelling, grammar, formatting, etc.

Comment: A couple of suggestions: **first**, use an editor that handles indentation for you. Yours is broken now, which makes it hard to read, and it'll show where your `{` and `}` don't match. **Second**, once you've fixed those typographical problems and it actually compiles, post it to code review. **Third**, if it gets complex (and it has), break it up into smaller parts which are simple enough to understand.

Comment: thanks for help all of you and i will take a look at the code review also useless if you're interested of the result of this "project" I'm doing i can send you a pm with the code once its done or once i have gotten to a point where i can see the finish line :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are probably loads of errors but the biggest one is that you have written too much bad code. Sorry to be harsh but it's true. The main lesson to learn is to write **small** chunks of code and get each chunk working before writing any more.

To take an example, this is wrong

```
int fraga;
...

                 cin >> fraga;
                 switch(fraga){
                              case '4':
```

Why is it wrong? Because fraga is an `int` but you say `case '4':` and `'4'` is a `char`. It should be

```
                 cin >> fraga;
                 switch(fraga){
                              case 4:
```

because `4` is an `int`.

A bit later you write

```
bool fail;
...
                                   cin >> fail;
                                   if(fail != '1'){
                                           fail = false;
                                           }
```

This is wrong because fail is a `bool`, so `fail != '1'` makes no sense because `'1'` is a `char` not a `bool`. See the issue? If you had taken the time to fix the first error, you would never have made the second error. There a lot of wasted effort in your program because you are trying to go too quickly.

You will find programming much easier if you take baby steps, at least while you are learning.

Comment: thx alot helped me feel free to point out other mistakes i've done or how i can make parts better anything will be appreciated :)

Comment: Please use punctuation and capitalise your words. It's difficult to read your sentences. You want to be understood, make it easy for people to understand you.